# USB keyboard stops working after unplugging/replugging 3 times in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

USB keyboard stops working after unplugging/replugging 3 times in Windows 10 on my PC. I have this same problem on my laptop since the start and couldn't find a solution. When I built the PC around 4 months backs, I did not have the problem. I don't know since when this issue started in my PC. But it is something that is acquired recently probably from updated drivers.

I can tell that the keyboard is detected by Windows because volume up and volume down and mute works. Not any other keys.

Also this is not the issue with the keyboard. When I hibernate and boot the PC, keyboard is detected and can be used at BIOS page. But once OS loads it stops working. Only solution is to perform a full restart.

Is this a common issue? Has anyone else faced the same problem and managed to fix it?

Steps I have tried which did not work

USB Selective Suspending is disabled in power options

"Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power" is unchecked for every device under USB controllers in device manager

Tried uninstalling USB devices which on reboot got auto installed

PS. Same issue occurs for mouse when unplugged/plugged after 6 times. Mouse is detected under devices and printeres. But buttons doesn't work.

Comment: Three times is what Windows will restart a crashed driver/service. This lists all drivers/services `sc query type= all`. See which one has changed when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: @user1292580 Thanks for the tip. I did what you suggested. Took dump of this command when keyboard works and when it doesn't. Nothing has changed and both the data is exactly matching though.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have this same issue with my keyboard and mouse, only more like after 6 times of unplugging. Do you have any Corsair drivers or services running like I do? It happens even for a cheap Dell keyboard, but I wonder if there's something lingering around from my Corsair gaming keyboard. Reinstalling/upgrading keyboard and USB drivers didn't help. When the issue happens, no other keyboards work, even when plugged into a different USB port. Oddly, the volume/media/macro/sleep keys still work on my keyboards, but nothing else. Always have to restart Windows.

Comment: @thatWiseGuy nope. I've not found a solution. Also I don't have corsair drivers. It happens with all keyboards and mouse, has nothing do with brand. Moreover, it only started happening only after few months. I assume it has to do with windows USB drivers. Try downgrading them if you can, I couldn't find any older drivers.